# asynchronous HTTP POST requests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a code which posts HTTP request sequentially for all the tuples in a list and append the response to another list.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www....'
input_list = [(1,2),(6,4),(7,8)]
output_list = []

for i in input_list:
   resp = (requests.post('url',data = i[1]).text,i[0])
   output_list.append(resp)

print(output_list)
```

Can someone please help me with the directions to make the HTTP requests in parallel ?

Comment: You can do it in two ways, either using multiprocessing (all at once) or asynchronously (one by one, but overlapping while executing), You have to first decide what is the most time consuming part, is that you have to wait a lot after you make the request, then I can help you write a solution with async programming or does the processing of the whole loop take the most time, then I can help you with multiprocessing, but first you have to decide which concurrency approach gives the best solution for your problem.

Comment: @SAK, There is not a big wait time i'll say. So async programming will be a good suit for my problem.

Comment: If there is no wait time after sending the request then async programming will actually make it slower, for example if you make the request and it takes 500 ms to get the response then while the system waits for the response it will execute the next iteration in the loop, instead if it only takes like 5ms to complete then async will actually add more overhead and make it slower.

Comment: @SAK, Each request is taking ~60 ms. Which approach do you think will be efficient ?

Comment: 60ms is actually way to less for multiprocessing and not suitable for async, but that said if you really want to save time in this case it would be setting up a multiprocessing pool executor which is the most easiest and standard way of doing in python.
I would post an answer with the multiprocessing solution in a shortwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `requests` library doesn't support asyncio natively, I'd use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, assuming the most of the time is spent waiting for IO. Otherwise it might be beneficial to use `multiprocessing.Pool`

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import requests

url = 'https://www....'
input_list = [(1,2),(6,4),(7,8)]

def get_url(i):
  return (requests.post('url',data = i[1]).text,i[0])

with ThreadPool(10) as pool: #ten requests to run in paralel
  output_list = list(pool.map(get_url, input_list))
```

Comment: threadpool is now `min(32, your_cpu+4)` so you no need to define workers, moreover `asyncio.to_thread` looks much more neat